# error - TypeError: React__namespace.useSyncExternalStore is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have an react nextjs typescript project whenever i tried to run

```
npm run dev
```

it throws an error like this

error - TypeError: React__namespace.useSyncExternalStore is not a function

sometimes with other functions like useSyncExternalStore

Answer (score 13):

```
yarn add react-dom@latest react@latest
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: This actually worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: @GertArnold you have to upgrade to react@18

Comment: Maybe you can explain that in the answer.

Comment: works with next.js as well. just as a side note I got this error because I installed chakra-ui and had to force override the dependencies that in question that caused the error. Thanks for the help!

Comment: To make it work with next.js you have to also run `yarn add next@latest` along.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error when adding Chakra to an existing project and `yarn add react-dom@latest react@latest` resolved it for me mentioned in the first solution

Error for reference:
`Uncaught TypeError: (0 , import_react236.useSyncExternalStore) is not a function`